# ReactJS setState to blank object not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have state like this

```
state = {
        params: {}
    }
```

let say we set the params by `this.setState({params:{data:2}})` then when we want to revert back to its initial state we call `this.setState({params:{}})`. The state is reverted, but the problem is that the view still render 2 (value of this.state.params.data). The only way that working is i call `this.setState({params:{data:''}})`. Imagine if we have many fields, we wont't do that. Is there any solution?

Link for codesandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-bird-8nrd5)

Comment: I dont see the issue you're having when I try to replicate it in this sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-dirac-mr6oy

Comment: Have you checked console for errors? I'm assuming, your code would look like `<...>{ this.state.params.data }</...>`. But when you set `params: {}`, that code will return `undefined`. This will work but if you have nay further levels, you will break code. If code throws error, execution is halted and hence no re-render

Comment: Maybe you have the shouldComponentUpdate method not working correctly.

Comment: i Updated the question, please kindly check it. I thin it is the problem wit react semantic ui @ChristopherNgo

Comment: i Updated the question, please kindly check it. I thin it is the problem wit react semantic ui @Rajesh

Comment: @MatiusNugrohoAryanto see my solution below. That should resolve it for you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve this by using a ternary operator for the value property. See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-clarke-l2pif

```
<Input
   value={params["data"] ? params["data"] : ""}
   onChange={(e, { value }) => {
      this.buildParams("data", value);
   }}
/>
```

This will work because it forces the semantic-ui tag to conditionally check for the value in our state, instead of using a static binding like `params.data`. If there is a `data` property in the object, then we will use its value. If not, then display an empty string.

The value used by the input is controlled at all times and will not be retained when reverting `params` to `{}` . I'm assuming you can swap data with a specific `name` or `key` corresponding to each input.

Comment: This is not semantic UI issue, it's React behaviour when changing uncontrolled input to controlled and vice versa.

Comment: @Clarity you're right, and now that you mention it, my code does resolve the issue regarding controlled and uncontrolled inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `this.setState({params:{}})` will set the `params` to an empty object on the state. To verify you can log the new state in the callback:

```
this.setState({params:{}}, () => console.log(this.state)) // {params: {}}
```

Edit: Looking at the updated question, the issue you're having is that your state is connected to the input via `this.state.params.data`. In this case when you set the state `params` to an empty object, the value of input will be set to `undefined` and you'll get a warning: `A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled.`

In this case your default state has to look like this:

```
this.state = {
  params: {data: ''}
}
```

and the reset method:

```
revertState = () => {
    this.setState({
      params: {data: ''}
    });
  };
```

Alternatively you can make your input uncontrolled by removing `value` prop, but in that case you won't be able to modify it directly.

Comment: please kindly check my updated question, is it problem with semantic ui?